# error: ‘app’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run the examples in the super bible version 7 in Ubuntu. I've successfully done this in Windows, however, with Ubuntu, it throws this error

```
sb7.h:346:8: error: ‘app’ was not declared in this scope
     a *app = new a;                                 
        ^
main.cpp:18:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘DECLARE_MAIN’
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application());
^
```

the `main.cpp` is

```
#ifndef _LINUX
#define _LINUX
#endif

#include "sb7.h"

class my_application : public sb7::application
{
public:
    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        static const GLfloat red[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
    }
};

DECLARE_MAIN(my_application());
```

and `sb7.h`

```
#ifndef __SB7_H__
#define __SB7_H__

#ifdef WIN32
    #pragma once
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1

    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1
    #include <Windows.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define Sleep(t) sleep(t)
#endif

#include "GL/gl3w.h"

#define GLFW_NO_GLU 1
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB 1

#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#include "sb7ext.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

namespace sb7
{

class application
{
private:
    static void APIENTRY debug_callback(GLenum source,
                                        GLenum type,
                                        GLuint id,
                                        GLenum severity,
                                        GLsizei length,
                                        const GLchar* message,
                                        GLvoid* userParam);

public:
    application() {}
    virtual ~application() {}
    virtual void run(sb7::application* the_app)
    {
        bool running = true;
        app = the_app;

        if (!glfwInit())
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
            return;
        }

        init();

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, info.majorVersion);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, info.minorVersion);

#ifndef _DEBUG
        if (info.flags.debug)
#endif /* _DEBUG */
        {
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);
        }
        if (info.flags.robust)
        {
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_ROBUSTNESS, GLFW_LOSE_CONTEXT_ON_RESET);
        }
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, info.samples);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STEREO, info.flags.stereo ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE);
//        if (info.flags.fullscreen)
//        {
//            if (info.windowWidth == 0 || info.windowHeight == 0)
//            {
//                GLFWvidmode mode;
//                glfwGetDesktopMode(&mode);
//                info.windowWidth = mode.Width;
//                info.windowHeight = mode.Height;
//            }
//
//            glfwOpenWindow(info.windowWidth, info.windowHeight, 8, 8, 8, 0, 32, 0, GLFW_FULLSCREEN);
//            glfwSwapInterval((int)info.flags.vsync);
//        }
//        else
        {
            window = glfwCreateWindow(info.windowWidth, info.windowHeight, info.title, info.flags.fullscreen ? glfwGetPrimaryMonitor() : NULL, NULL);
            if (!window)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open window\n");
                return;
            }
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, glfw_onResize);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, glfw_onKey);
        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, glfw_onMouseButton);
        glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, glfw_onMouseMove);
        glfwSetScrollCallback(window, glfw_onMouseWheel);
        if (!info.flags.cursor)
        {
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN);
        }

        // info.flags.stereo = (glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_STEREO) ? 1 : 0);

        gl3wInit();

#ifdef _DEBUG
        fprintf(stderr, "VENDOR: %s\n", (char *)glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
        fprintf(stderr, "VERSION: %s\n", (char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
        fprintf(stderr, "RENDERER: %s\n", (char *)glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
#endif

        if (info.flags.debug)
        {
            if (gl3wIsSupported(4, 3))
            {
                glDebugMessageCallback((GLDEBUGPROC)debug_callback, this);
                glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
            }
            else if (sb6IsExtensionSupported("GL_ARB_debug_output"))
            {
                glDebugMessageCallbackARB((GLDEBUGPROC)debug_callback, this);
                glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS_ARB);
            }
        }

        startup();

        do
        {
            render(glfwGetTime());

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();

            running &= (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_RELEASE);
            running &= (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) != GL_TRUE);
        } while (running);

        shutdown();

        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    virtual void init()
    {
        strcpy(info.title, "OpenGL SuperBible Example");
        info.windowWidth = 800;
        info.windowHeight = 600;
#ifdef __APPLE__
        info.majorVersion = 3;
        info.minorVersion = 2;
#else
        info.majorVersion = 4;
        info.minorVersion = 3;
#endif
        info.samples = 0;
        info.flags.all = 0;
        info.flags.cursor = 1;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        info.flags.debug = 1;
#endif
    }

    virtual void startup()
    {

    }

    virtual void render(double currentTime)
    {

    }

    virtual void shutdown()
    {

    }

    void setWindowTitle(const char * title)
    {
        glfwSetWindowTitle(window, title);
    }

    virtual void onResize(int w, int h)
    {
        info.windowWidth = w;
        info.windowHeight = h;
    }

    virtual void onKey(int key, int action)
    {

    }

    virtual void onMouseButton(int button, int action)
    {

    }

    virtual void onMouseMove(int x, int y)
    {

    }

    virtual void onMouseWheel(int pos)
    {

    }

    virtual void onDebugMessage(GLenum source,
                                GLenum type,
                                GLuint id,
                                GLenum severity,
                                GLsizei length,
                                const GLchar* message)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        OutputDebugStringA(message);
        OutputDebugStringA("\n");
#endif /* _WIN32 */
    }

    void getMousePosition(int& x, int& y)
    {
        double dx, dy;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &dx, &dy);

        x = static_cast<int>(floor(dx));
        y = static_cast<int>(floor(dy));
    }

public:
    struct APPINFO
    {
        char title[128];
        int windowWidth;
        int windowHeight;
        int majorVersion;
        int minorVersion;
        int samples;
        union
        {
            struct
            {
                unsigned int    fullscreen  : 1;
                unsigned int    vsync       : 1;
                unsigned int    cursor      : 1;
                unsigned int    stereo      : 1;
                unsigned int    debug       : 1;
                unsigned int    robust      : 1;
            };
            unsigned int        all;
        } flags;
    };

protected:
    APPINFO     info;
    static      sb7::application * app;
    GLFWwindow* window;

    static void glfw_onResize(GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h)
    {
        app->onResize(w, h);
    }

    static void glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        app->onKey(key, action);
    }

    static void glfw_onMouseButton(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
    {
        app->onMouseButton(button, action);
    }

    static void glfw_onMouseMove(GLFWwindow* window, double x, double y)
    {
        app->onMouseMove(static_cast<int>(x), static_cast<int>(y));
    }

    static void glfw_onMouseWheel(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
    {
        app->onMouseWheel(static_cast<int>(yoffset));
    }

    void setVsync(bool enable)
    {
        info.flags.vsync = enable ? 1 : 0;
        glfwSwapInterval((int)info.flags.vsync);
    }
};

};

#if defined _WIN32
#define DECLARE_MAIN(a)                             \
sb7::application *app = 0;                          \
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,           \
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,       \
                     LPSTR lpCmdLine,               \
                     int nCmdShow)                  \
{                                                   \
    a *app = new a;                                 \
    app->run(app);                                  \
    delete app;                                     \
    return 0;                                       \
}
#elif defined _LINUX || defined __APPLE__
#define DECLARE_MAIN(a)                             \
int main(int argc, const char ** argv)              \
{                                                   \
    a *app = new a;                                 \
    app->run(app);                                  \
    delete app;                                     \
    return 0;                                       \
}
#else
#error Undefined platform!
#endif

#endif /* __SB7_H__ */
```

The makefile is

```
CXX        = g++
CXXFLAGS   = -Wall -W -std=c++11
LD         = g++


INCLUDEDIR = /home/XXX/CPP_Projects/ModernOpenGL/sb7code-master/include
LIBDIR     = /home/XXX/CPP_Projects/ModernOpenGL/sb7code-master/build/lib
LIBFILE    = -lsb7 -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -ldl -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt -lm -lpthread


INCLUDES   = -I$(INCLUDEDIR)
LIBS       = -L$(LIBDIR) $(LIBFILE)

EXEEXT     = .exe

TARGET     = test
EXECUTABLE = $(TARGET)$(EXEEXT)

OBJS       = $(TARGET).o

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET)

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)$(EXEEXT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application());
```

probably should be this:

```
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application);
```

Because `my_application` is a class, and your macro is expecting you to pass the name of the class.

Side note: And all of this, is one reason for staying away from macros.

Comment: One question, in my case I'm using `make TARGET=main` and the name of `.exe` is test as indicated in my makefile but the makefile ignores test and rename the `.exe` as main.exe. Any suggestion why the makefile fails to yield `test.exe`

Comment: Why do you need to pass the `TARGET=main` to the make command? that should be the reason, you are overwriting the TARGET value from the definition inside the makefile.

Comment: This makefile is not mine, however, in some cases, actually it works but not always the case. I have no idea why.

Comment: I'm not talking about the makefile, but the make command you are initiating. just run `make` with no parameters.

Comment: It throws this error `make: *** No rule to make target test.o`

Comment: I'm really not so familiar with writing the Makefile manually, but I guess you should either rename the main.cpp to test.cpp or change the `OBJS`'s value to main.o . but that's just a guess based on what I see here.